# Dubuging problem in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in my project when i build the project it is giving this message :

To debug this module, change its project build configuration to debug mode. To suppress this message, disable the "Warn inf no user code on launch" debugger option

due to this when i place the break point. break point is not working. can u help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check that the *Standard* toolbar shows that you are working in *Debug* mode. This is the most common cause for this problem. This setting controls what mode the *Run* will use. (Too see this toolbar, right click in the Visual Studio menu area and make sure the 'Standard' toolbar is checked.)
- Check that you are not running with ctrl+f5 (which equals *Start Without Debugging*). This does not match the error message you get, so likely not the answer.
- Check that the *Solution Configuration* does not specify that the project should be built in Release mode. To access this, right click the solution, see properties for the solution and then review the configuration settings for your projects in the configuration dialog editor that pops up.

Comment: i make them debug from release and uncheck the check box it is not working Mr. Jorn Jensen

Comment: If you uncheck it, the project will not be built. This is not the solution. They should all build. And the Debug version should build using the Debug configuration, whilst the Release version should build the Release configuration. Take one step back and look at the 'Standard' toolbar, there should be a dropdown where you choose between Debug and Release.

Comment: no Mr.Jorn it is getting same message and break point is not working.

Comment: I think you are running the solution in release mode, as ArsenMkrt  wrote. Double check that you can see the Debug/Release dropdown in the menu, just to the right of the green *run* arrow (vs2008).


And if you change the build configuration for a project, you might want to rebuild all.

Comment: Mr. Jorn i did like this message is not displaying but break point is not working. i did like this tools >> option >> Debug >> (uncheck the check box) Enable Just My Code

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to debug your project in Release mode... Switch the project into Debug mode, click Rebuild and then press F5.

Comment: actually my project has 3 tier architecture. in my project solution explorere three projects are ther businsesslayer and data layer and presentation layer.

Comment: i did like this right click on project solution explorer >> properties. The property window contain  configuration:Active(Debug),platform:Active(Any(CPU)).

configuration 

Project       |  configuration |  platform |  Debut

businesslayer | Debug          |Any CPU    | Un check the chekbox
Datalyer      | Debug          |Any CPU    | Un check the chekbox
Frentend      | Debug          |.NET       | Un check the chekbox